# Get last insert id in store function

Tags: laravel-backpack

How to get the last insert id in backpack for laravel 4 in the store function?

```
public function store()
{
   
    $response = $this->traitStore();
    //need the last id for operations
    return $response;
}
```

This code doesn't work for me:

```
$id = $this->crud->entry->id; // <-- SHOULD WORK
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have the last inserted item available as `$this->data['entry']`, so you should be able to get the ID using `$this->data['entry']->id`